# SOLVED ! how do i implement videoplayback in my nativescript application?

Tags: android, video, nativescript

I record video with the nativescript-videorecorder and play it back from the saved file from the nativescript-videoplayer plugin. In iOS it works like a dream, but in android the most i can achieve is a black screen ( with sound only if i use the exoplayer). I have the latest version of nativescript and plugins. my project uses webpack. The examples found on the web , linked to the mentioned plugins, do not work either.Can anyone shine a light on this issue ?

```
function takeVideo()
```

{
    var options = {
        saveToGallery: false,
        duration: 10,
        size: 300,
        hd: false,
        explanation: ''
    }

```
 var permreq = [];
if(isAndroid) permreq = [android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA];    
permissions.requestPermission(permreq, "Uw toestemming is nodig om video-opnamen te kunnen maken.")
.then(function () 
{     
    permissions.requestPermission([android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], 'We hebben toegang tot het bestandssysteem nodig om uw bestand op te slaan').then(function () {
        var videorecorder = new vr.VideoRecorder(options);
        videorecorder.record(options).then(data => {
            // get file from data here
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

}
exports.takeVideo = takeVideo;

The playback in ios works fine. for android i can not get my saved mp4 file to work, and also the undermentioned url does not render a pictur to the display.

```
 <StackLayout   id = "zoomvideo" className="collapse"  height = "100%" verticalAlignment="top">  

                                            <VideoPlayer:Video height="100%" row="1"   
                                            loaded="videoplayerLoaded"  
                                            src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" 
                                            finished="videoFinished" controls="true" 
                                            autoplay="false"  id = "vidplayer" fill = "true" />     </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Are you specifying a `format` while recording? Can you post related code, record & playback?

Comment: I have added the code to my post. Any insights are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem... In Android manifest the android:hardwareAccelerated="false" caused this problem. fixing that by setting it to true posed a new (less impacting ) problem. I now have shadows in some elements where background is transparent.... This is because with the hardwareAccelerated set to true, the z-index i used created unwanted elevation. i never noticed this because elevation does not work with hardwareAccelerated=false....